does the user provide the hash of passwd in NTLM authentication or the O.S or the system
can you guys help and explain why ?
i think GPT provide wrong answer
Which is true for NTLM/LM authentication?
a) Client sends login request and encrypted password to DC
b) Client sends login request and hash of password to DC
c) Client generates nonce, sends it to DC, DC encrypts it and send back to client
d) DC generates nonce, sends it to client, client encrypts it and send back to DC
i think if we look at the steps it will be clear but still i'm confused
